# Javascript - Show message when "No connectivity detected”

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

*Please note that this question is in consequence of another question: "[Codename One - ToastBar when “No connectivity detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844443/codename-one-toastbar-when-no-connectivity-detected)"*

What is a correct approach (in Javascript or JQuery) to deal with Internet connection unavailability (that is common on mobile devices)?

Every time that there is a networking error, I would like to show a message to the user (like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll6jD.png) and pause the Internet activity of the web page, in a way that no errors are generated (and the messages written by the user, for example in an html form, are not lost). The Internet activity should be (automatically) restored when the connection will be available again.

This should be a convenient way to allow people to interact with a web site (from mobile devices) without the risk of losing their posts or comments and without receive errors when they click a link.

This functionality should be as much as possible independent from the specific web site. What is a correct way to implement it?

Comment: What solutions have you looked at? What have you considered?

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Comment: Hossein's answer is probably correct, you can inject code into the page after the on-load event and that way detach it from the functionality of the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery plugin like this :
[Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

Comment: Thank you, it works well, I integrated it in a complex web site. However it's done by javascipt + css only, it doesn't require Jquery.